# How to make a button visible only to user in a multiple selection people field

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, power-automate, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm doing a SharePoint List automation and i need to make a button that only people from a specific field to be able to see it.

I have a column Actions for my button. And a column "Pessoas de atribuicao" with multiple people that keeps updating. Basically, i need to make this button only visible to this group of people

I'm using this code in display field, because it works when the column is a single person field. It just doesn't work when its multiple:

```
"display": "=if(([$Estado] == 'Documentação Cliente' && [$Pessoasdeatribui_x00e7__x00e3_o.email]== @me, 'block', 'none')"
```

I'm familiar with buttons in SharePoint and the column name is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use below expression, it should work for you:

```
"display": "=if([$Estado] == 'Documentação Cliente' && indexOf(join([$Pessoasdeatribui_x00e7__x00e3_o.email],';'), @me) != -1, 'block', 'none')"
```

Make sure you are using correct **internal names** of you SharePoint list columns. Follow this to check internal name of your columns: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON column formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped you. Keep using this platform to ask any questions about SharePoint.

Comment: Please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you and it will help others with similar question to find the correct answer easily.